# Irregular results while testing Angular services

Tags: angular, testing

I was trying to test an Angular service and I am facing this problem.
This is my service:

```
import { Ipersons } from './ipersons';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Ialbums } from './ialbums';

@Injectable()
export class AlbumService {
  albums: any;
  persons: any;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
   }
   getImages(start, limit)
   {
     const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start='+start+'&_limit='+limit;
      return this.http.get<Ialbums[]>(url);
   }
   getPersons(id)
   {
     const url= 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/'+id;
     return this.http.get<Ipersons[]>(url);
   }
}
```

Then this is my spec.ts:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { Ialbums } from './ialbums';
import { AlbumService } from './album.service';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
describe('AlbumService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [AlbumService, HttpClient]
    });
  });

  it('should be created', inject([AlbumService], (service: AlbumService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));
  fit('should return json array', inject([AlbumService], (service: AlbumService) => {
    service.getImages(1, 1).subscribe(result => {
      expect(result[0].id).toBe(4);
     });
  }));
});
```

When I am running the test it returns successful even when I actually am giving the wrong value to compare, for example result[0].id value is 2 but it returns success even when I give it to be 4.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

Comment: i want to test the service function instead of a http request @JB NIzet

Comment: And all your service does is to send an HTTP request. You really don't want to actually send requests to a backend in a unit test. Read the link I gave you again.

Comment: i am sorry but i am a new to this and i am kinda unable to follow can you write a small sample for how it would look like for my example @JB Nizet

Comment: i got it to work by doing this i was silly to make an http request synchronously i just added async and its working fine but i know it not correct to make actual request to test so kindly please help me!!Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The models examples I created for the purpose of this answer(you can change them as you wish):
`album.interface.ts`

```js
export interface IAlbum {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  year?: number;
}
```

`person.interface.ts`

```js
export interface IPerson {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  // ...
}
```

The service itself(I'v added typings and spaces):
`album.service.ts`

```js
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {IAlbum} from './album.interface';
import {IPerson} from './person.interface';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AlbumService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getImages(start: number, limit: number): Observable<IAlbum[]> {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_start=' + start + '&_limit=' + limit;
    return this.http.get<IAlbum[]>(url);
  }

  getPersons(id: number): Observable<IPerson[]> {
    const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/' + id;
    return this.http.get<IPerson[]>(url);
  }
}
```

The tests:
`album.service.spec.ts`

```js
import {inject, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';
import {AlbumService} from './album.service';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {IAlbum} from './album.interface';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';

describe('AlbumService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      // We are going to mock HttpClient. For this task, we can use angular's dependency injection system.
      // we will provide a mock instead the original http service.
      {
        // first we need to tell what we are providing.
        provide: HttpClient,

        // here we will tell angular to create a new mock and provide it for each test.
        // you can also use `useValue` and provide the same value for all the tests.
        useFactory: () => jasmine.createSpyObj('HttpClient', ['get'])
      },
      AlbumService
    ]

    // notice we don't need to import HttpClientModule, as out mock is replacing it and we aren't
    // using any other functionality from the module.
  }));

  it('should be created', inject([AlbumService], (service: AlbumService) => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  }));

  fit('should return json array', inject([AlbumService, HttpClient], (service: AlbumService, httpClient) => {
    // the album that will be returned first in the list of albums.
    const album: IAlbum = {
      albumId: 1,
      id: 1,
      title: 'accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt',
      url: 'https://via.placeholder.com/600/92c952',
      thumbnailUrl: 'https://via.placeholder.com/150/92c952'
    };

    // creating a stub that will be returned instead of the real http response.
    const albums$: Observable<IAlbum[]> = of([
      album
    ]);

    // making the http mock's get function return the list of albums we created.
    httpClient.get.and.returnValue(albums$);

    // as we have mocked the response, it returnes synchronously, and we don't need the async part.
    service.getImages(1, 1).subscribe(result => {
      expect(result[0].id).toEqual(album.id);
      expect(result[0].id).not.toEqual(album.id + 1);
    });

    // you can see now that the get function of the http mock client we created have been called.
    expect(httpClient.get).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});
```

notes:

1. For more information about angular testing you can look [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing)
2. notice I have changed the names from `Iperson` to `IPerson`. this is the proper way to write the names of types, with a capital letters in the start of each word.
3. I reccomand adding language hinting that will add colors to your code samples. You only need to add the name of the language in the start of each code sample. look [here](https://help.github.com/en/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks) for more information.